# How to put the marker with google maps query string

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I can share a location with google maps providing the lat and lon parameters. For example;

http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.01696,32.33076&z=17

With the "ll" parameter i can center the map there. Is there a way to put the marker to the position specified?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use 'q' on its own as in:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.01696,32.33076&z=17

then you will get a green pointer at the point of the coordinates provided but you'll also get an unwanted additional red marker for a nearby point of interest, which doesn't look good and can be confusing for the viewer.

Best option is to use 'q=loc:' as in:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:40.01696,32.33076&z=17

This will only display a single red marker for the coordinates provided and centres the map on that point.

Comment: I don't see any green marker in either case.  Just the red one.

Answer (score 1):

Just use "q". It'll put a marker there.

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.01696,32.33076&

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter `saddr` .

It's actually  meant to place a marker for the start of a route, but you may use it to place a marker and share the location(including the marker)

But of course you also can save a public map and share it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following:

[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers][1]

I've just been looking at doing the same thing come up with something along the lines of:

&markers=color:0xd94bf9%7Clabel:A%7C25.250327,55.3332642

So here I have the color, label text and location separated by %7C for the pipe delimiters detailed in the API